# processing onChange with ajax, txtBox.text control doesnt match form.request(txtBox)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a form that autosaves on blur of each control. 
This functionality works.

There are a 3 fields  that required some additional processing, so I thought that for those 3, triggering off change INSTEAD might save a few cpu cycles on the server.

for those fields, i removed the normal blur handler, and added a special handler. 
I use the jquery.off() , jquery.blur(), and jquery.change() methods.

The special handler first calls save() (exact same routine as the normal handler ) and then does the extra calculations when save() completes successfully.

when called from **blur**, the save function works perfectly. 
I am using the jquery.form plug in. The call posts to the page itself. (as opposed to a shared webmethod)
I have yet to catch it missing an updated value, and I have tried.

When change() calls the same function from the **change** event, I get odd behavior.

In save( )  txtLength.text give the old value. 
request.form(txtLength.UniqueID) gives the new value.

The call chain on the server originates in form_Load.

From what I read on the form  [lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), all the controls should be loaded by then.

One solution is to just call the special handler from blur() for those 3 controls. This is acceptable, but it means gave up without trying to really understand whats going on.

I am wondering if anyone can explain why the form acts different in response to blur and change events.

Have i misinterpreted the lifecycle. Is some other form event a better choice than load() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had time to isolate this. It appears that telerik radtextboxes are the culprit.

If i replace them with regular text boxes, i get the expected behaviour.